# Drag and paste a cell value of out an html table that is first generated from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have dynamically created an HTML table using PHP and querying from a MySQL database.

Once this table is created, I would like to drag and drop (actually drag and paste) specific cell values into another table.

I am using the following javascript/jquery and HTML5 to create this drag and drop functionality.  I

```js
<script>

function dragStart(event)
{
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text",event.target.id);
}


function allowDrop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.target.style.color = 'blue'
}
    
function drag(event) {
        event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
        event.target.style.color = 'green';
    }
    
    function drop(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data=event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
        console.log(nodeCopy);
        nodeCopy.id = "newId"; /* We cannot use the same ID */
        event.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
    }
</script>
```

Here is a snippet of the code generating the table:

```js
$.ajax({
           method:"POST",
           url:"facility_id_dropdown.php?sid="+sid,
           contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType:"json",
           success: function(data){
           jsonURL="facility_id_dropdown.php?sid="+sid+".json";
           $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(data){
           var station_programming='';
           $.each(data, function(key, value){
                station_programming+='<tr>';
                station_programming+='<td>'+value.call_sign+'</td>';
                station_programming+='<td>'+value.facility_id+'</td>';
                station_programming+='<td>'+value.operator+'</td>';
                station_programming+='<td><span class="event" ] draggable="true" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">' +value.primary_programming+'</span></td>
```

As you can tell, I want to be able to drag the value.primary_programming.

I am getting the following error:
    "market_plans.php:150 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of null at drop"

I am guessing that it is somehow related to the fact that I am generating this table and do not have static IDs.

When I assign a static ID to a `<td>` in my table, I am able to see the cell value when I do an innerHTML.  But because my table will be of varying lengths and sizes I am not sure how to dynamically assign names.  I also do not think that this is helpful for the drag and paste functionality.

I have also tried modifying my code using:

```js
event.dataTransfer.setData("text", $(this).attribute('id'))
data=event.dataTransfer.getData("text",$(this).attribute('id'))
```

But these changes did not work either.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should not assign `id` attributes to any Node you intend to clone. `cloneNode()` duplicates the `id` and may cause other downstream problems. Alternatively you could set a `data-` attribute and pass that in `dataTransfer`. then query for the attribute value of the `data-` attribute. That should fix you up.

Comment: Thanks Randy.  Could I bother you for a clarification?   I got rid of id attribute and am now using the following:  station_programming+='<td draggable="true" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">'+value.primary_programming+'</td>'.  How would I set up the data- attribute with my dynamic variable?  Also, are you saying that I should change this setData statement to something other than text:  event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id)"?  Thanks again.

Comment: I think the easiest way to answer is to have you review this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/

Comment: Thanks again.   Can you check the link?

Comment: Whoops, a jsfiddle "feature". sorry about that. https://jsfiddle.net/Lghwca72/

Comment: Thanks again.  I will take a look.  At first glance it appears similar to what I saw previously in examples with static text...but maybe I will pick up something else that I missed.

Comment: Here are key points: There is no need putting anything in `dataTransfer`, there is no need to read from `dataTransfer`, set a context wide variable at `dragStart`, use that variable in `drop`. That's it. Your code is over complicated.